# Grub not showing up at boot

Tags: boot, grub2

I have installed the linux-lowlatency kernel recently.
Setup of a DAW (MIDI support) was the reason to change from Fedora to Ubuntu.

After reboot uname shows that I am running the generic kernel. 
There are 2 entries (normal and revovery) for the lowlatency kernel in 
/boot/grub/grub.cfg
but the grub menu does not show up at boot time at all.

... and no - I do not want to buy Windows software like an answer else where to this question suggests

Comment: have you tried reconfiguring/re-installing grub?

Comment: Sometimes GRUB can be configure to not show at boot at automatically boot to first entry. Try holding the left shift button at start-up to make it show.

Answer (score 1):

To enable the grub menu to select the kernel, you have to comment the line in `/etc/default/grub`

> `#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`

Then you have to run `update-grub` and reboot and the grub menu should appear.